# Is it possible to create full web site with Silverlight?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have never programmed web sites. I know that I can create web sites using ASP.
So is it possible to create full web site with Silverlight? Or does Silverlight only support web forms?

Comment: Please use your favorite search engine and this site's [silverlight wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/silverlight/info) to understand what Silverlight is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I suppose you could.

However, would it be the right choice for your target market?

- [Silverlight market share](http://www.statowl.com/silverlight.php) : 65%
- [Flash market share](http://www.statowl.com/flash.php) : 95%
- Javscript - pretty much everyone
- HTML - everyone

If you're tarketing the whole world, personally I wouldn't use silverlight for the whole site, just for features that required it (and even then, I'd write a HTML only backup version for people who don't have silverlight).

However, if you're writing it for a company that you *know* has silverlight installed and you're familiar with silverlight then go for it!

Answer (score 2):

theoretically it's possible, but I don't think it's really recommended when some environments stop supporting plug-ins as java/flash/silverlight...

I suppose Html5 is the best choice for web development.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flow chart to help you in your decision

[Pick your platform](http://www.gliffy.com/publish/2926782/)